# gerrit upgrade to 3.3.0 casues heavy load

Tags: gerrit

Recently upgraded gerrit to version 3.3.0 from version 2.15.17 and after the upgrade the load is high on the gerrit server. It is a 12 core CPU linux with 62GB RAM and all the cores are used 100% always. Also, the CPU percentage usage always is 1000% by the gerrit process .Java heap memory is set to 42Gb. Could you please let me know how can the gerrit be tuned in order to improve the performance

Comment: How have you made the upgrade? All upgrades from any 2.x version to a 3.x version require to upgrade first to version 2.16.

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned here https://groups.google.com/u/2/g/repo-discuss/c/G5wucKJg9Ag. Upgarded from 2.15.17 -> 2.15.22->2.16->2.16.2->3.0.1->3.0.16->3.1.0->3.1.13->3.2.0->3.2.8->3.3.0

Comment: Does the logs/error_log file have some clue?

Comment: no suspicious error in the error log. I need to restart the gerrit service everytime when the load goes high .